# Best approach for adding subviews in tableview cell at runtime and expand tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

[image] [image]

I have a table view (picture attached) where I have a cell and its status(multiple).

When a user clicks the cell it expands show the status.

My question is what is the best approach to achieve this functionality, I don't feel like the one I have right is a good approach.

Right now when a user click I set a variable in didSelectRowAt and reload the cell. When I reload the cell I check the variable and add/remove subview.

I'm adding subview in a stackview like this:-

```
    for _ in 1...4 {
        let view = ActivityFeedStatusView()
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
                                            toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 70.0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraint])
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }
```

As you can see it'll get added all the time `cellForRowAt` will be called plus It is also giving me constraint warning.

I'm open to any kind of feedback and suggestions, thank you for reading.

> Note: This code is just a test code to generate and show view

Comment: The simplest way is to use the section table view

Comment: True but the thing is I already have three sections like pin, unpin and other and the cell is part of the section. the section itself has different functionalities and it'll heavy to do that in my case. I'm thinking about making the status view cell and adding/deleting them at runtime.

Comment: @tryKuldeepTanwar I don't see a problem with your solution. Just keep track of the cell(s) you want to show status for and reload those rows when selected. Of course, you'll need some logic for hiding the status for unwanted cells as well.

Comment: But views are being added every time cellForRowAt is called, do you think it's the right approach @RobertCrabtree

Comment: @tryKuldeepTanwar Every time cellForRowAt is called you should remove all status views. Then if the cell should be showing status add your status views. Does that answer your question? If not, I'm not sure what your concern is.

Comment: You can move that title cell to the section headerView and status part to the row. Not sure whether this was the discussion at the top regarding section table view.

Comment: You can also use StackView. Instead of adding or removing subviews, you can simply hide its views. That will take far less time than adding or removing.
Just another approach.

Comment: @MuhammadUmerFarooq The data will be in 100's of records, it's like a notification screen

Answer (score -1):

Your solution seems fine to me:
My complete solution is:
1.keep track of previous selected cell index and current selected cell index by delegate method didSelectCellAtIndex.
2.reload cells at previous cell index and current cell index.
3.in cell init codes.if it is at previous then remove all status subviews.Otherwise,add status subviews on this cell.
4.manually calculate the height and reload or use auto layout for self height constraint.

Comment: one more suggestion is that make status view a seperate class,and draw those status instead of adding subviews because I guess user interactive is not needed here.By drawing on canvas will achieve a better drawing performance.

Comment: Your proposed approach has a performance issues where scrolling such table view won't be smooth.

Comment: @MarekBaláž not tested on my side.but you can always cache status if status comes from an api.then you will not face a api lagging when you scroll if that is what you mentioned.

Comment: Its not a problem on API side, but data driven custom adding/removing views is not good approach because of reusability of table view cells. For such things there is collection view that will handle it for you without any performance issues.

Comment: Add collectionView here as subview to each cell is way heavy here.add/remove simple views here will not affect performance if my opinion.even if will,like I suggested,draw the chart instead of use subviews.

Comment: There is nothing heavy on adding collectionView atleast I dont know about it then. Less code doesnt mean lighter solution.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with cell height in your previous story and that makes you feel dynamic add/remove subviews is a must-not.